# Collection View NSException

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I connected my collection to the to the delegate and the data source, but I'm still getting this error.  What is unrecognized about my implementation of the numberOfItmesInSection method?  I can post more of the error if needed, seems like this is the gist of it.

From console:

Error: -[UIViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    var list = ["Laundry", "Do Dishes", "Vaccuum", "Run around", "Sing a song", "Get a grip", "Shoot a buffalo", "Space out", "Eat bork", "Apply to job", "Scuba doobey", "Polka Dance Marathon", "Pizza Catastrophe"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: StandardCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as StandardCell
        cell.CellLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: plese once refer this link..it may be useful for your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707662/uicollectionview-datasource-delegate-related-exception

Comment: [collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [collectionView setDataSource:self]; write like this in viewDidLoad

Comment: Check the class of the view controller in the storyboard that has the collection view. Its class needs to be ViewController, but the error is saying that the collection view is trying to call its data source methods on a UIViewController.

Comment: Yep, you'd better check the objects in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not working in swift as of now. You can check the below code from Apple reference document. There is an underscore but I am not sure this will help or not.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Answer (score 0):

As @rdelmar mentioned in the comments, I set my view controller class in the storyboard to View Controller instead of UIViewController, and that did the trick.  I don't remember having to do that in the past when doing similar things with tableViews, but in any case that was the solution.  Thanks!